# Checking for old and new file, creating one if nothing exists with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

So I'm trying to write a script for Windows to check and see if both an old and a new outlook profile exists for a user. If an old one exists but a new one doesn't, it copies the old one and gives it a new file name.

I have a general idea of the syntax, looks something like this.

```
If Exist \users\%%UserName%%\%%OldFileName%% 

   If NOT Exist \users\%%UserName%%\%%NewFileName%% 

      copy \users\%%UserName%%\%%OldFileName%%  \users\%%UserName%%\%%NewFileName%% 

   End If

End If
```

**UPDATED!**
Here's what I've been able to come up with so far.

```
Dim objFSO

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        strOldFileName = “Default Outlook Profile.NK2”
        strNewFileName = “Default Profile.NK2”

    If objFSO.FileExists "\\comfilesrv1\users\%%UserName%%\&OldFileName&" Then
        objFSO.CopyFile "\\comfilesrv1\users\%%UserName%%\&OldFileName&", "\\comfilesrv1\users\%%UserName%%\&NewFileName&"
    End If
```

I'm not asking for anyone to write this for me, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: `&` is the string concatenation operator in VBScript, I don't see what you want to achieve with the `%%` syntax. There is a `Copy` method in the file system object, which, by the way, is well [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. The % was a placeholder for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim objFSO, strOldFileName, strNewFileName, strOldProfile, strNewprofile, bOverwrite

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
bOverwrite = true

strOldFileName = "Default Outlook Profile.NK2"
strNewFileName = "Default Profile.NK2"

strOldProfile = "\\comfilesrv1\users\" & UserName & "\" & strOldFileName
strNewprofile = "\\comfilesrv1\users\" & UserName & "\" & strNewFileName

If objFSO.FileExists(strOldProfile) Then
  objFSO.CopyFile strOldProfile, strNewprofile, bOverwrite
End If
```